# Django, south, postgres initial migration error

Tags: django, postgresql, django-south

I am using south and django on a new site with a postgres database. I am attempting to do the initial migration but get the following error

> django.db.utils.DatabaseError: invalid input syntax for integer: ""

when this line is called

```
('views', self.gf('django.db.models.fields.IntegerField')(default=0)),
```

which translates to this in the model

```
views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

This all works fine with sqllite locally, anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: For some reason setting the default to 1 fixed the issue

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned in your comments, setting the default to 1 fixed the problem.  I understand you'd like some idea of why.

sqlite stores most data as strings, so '' is a perfectly valid value there.  PostgreSQL provides strict checking so you can't send '' but NULL is acceptable.