# Getting: invalid input syntax for uuid: "" when using django-uuidfield as primary key for a model

Tags: python, django, uuid

I have the following model class that uses *django-uuidfield* as primary key:

```
class FODType(models.Model):
    id = UUIDField(auto=True, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

From the admin, I try to create an entry for this model but i get the following error:

> DataError at /admin/Bleary/fodtype/add/ invalid input syntax for uuid:
>   "" LINE 1: ... WHERE "Bleary_fodtype"."id" = ''

`UUIDField` in the model is set to autocreate a value if none is specified, but in this case the empty string is being specified as the value for the primary key on the save. Since the primary key has a value, its trying to do an update instead of an insert and failing.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What version of *django* and *django-uuidfield* do you use?

Comment: Django==1.6.1
Markdown==2.3.1
Pygments==1.6
django-filter==0.7
django-uuidfield==0.4.0
djangorestframework==2.3.10
psycopg2==2.5.1

Comment: I've hacked up a solution in fields.py for uuidfield: if it was called with value parameter set to empty string, it wasnt creating a new uuid. The admin was calling it with empty string. So I updated  get_db_prep_value to account for that case.

Comment: It's weird you're getting this error, I have the same setup and it works properly. Do you have any customized admin classes?

Comment: Not sure if this could help you: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7451465/django-south-postgres-initial-migration-error

Answer (score 0):

Please note that  django-UUDField implementation does not reflect the expected behaviour when used as primary-key, if the save() fails for any reason the value of the field persist so that checking obj.pk cannot be used anymore to check if the object is stored or not.